# In the film "Limitless" (2011), why were the murder incidents relating to Eddie Morra downplayed by police?

Tags: plot-explanation, limitless

In [*Limitless* (2011)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1219289/):

1. Eddie Morra was at the apartment just before and after the murder of Vernon Gant. He also called the police.
2. Eddie Morra was at the hotel-room when the "blonde" was murdered.
3. Gennady and his Russian's associates were killed in Eddie Morra's apartment.

Now, why does Eddie not seem to be affected by these incidents throughout the movie?

Comment: I had the same thoughts. I'm wondering if there were scenes deleted related to the murders.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They actually explained how he got out of all these situations:

> 1. Eddie Morra was at the apartment just before and after the murder of Vernon Gant. He also called the police.

Gant was a known drug dealer and so it's not unlikely for him to have enemies. Eddie was his ex-brother-in-law, so it's not too strange that he would show up at his apartment. The police interviewed him, but there was no evidence for his involvement.

> 2. Eddie Morra was at the hotel-room when the "blonde" was murdered.

There was a witness who identified Eddie in a picture from a newspaper article. At this point Eddie gets help from one of the best attorneys in criminal law, who manages to get him off by setting up the [police lineup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Police_lineup) with a bunch of Eddie-look-alikes, so that the witness cannot identify him. Later we find out that the lawyer was actually sent to steal his NZT stash.

> 3. Gennady and his Russian's associates were killed in Eddie Morra's apartment.

This was explained as well. The police came to the conclusion that the Russians were actually looking for an earlier owner of the loft, who was an arms dealer. It's likely that Eddie gave them that idea with some help from NZT.

Answer (score 8):

The entire point of the movie is that the drug gives Eddie the ability to think his way out of situations which would be completely impossible for normal people to. Since people already regularly get away with murder, it would be almost trivial for Eddie to figure out ways to convincingly alibi himself out of anything the police might want to pin on him. However, I do think this is an oversight on the part of the script, and should have been dealt with more explicitly.